# Is Love $\subseteq$ Person $\times$ Person an equivalence relation, partial order or total order?

Tags: relations, order-theory, predicate-logic, equivalence-relations

Is the predicate Love $\subseteq$ Person $\times$ Person a equivalence relation, partial order or total order?
Love $\subseteq$ Person $\times$ Person is valid if $x$ loves $y.$

My conclusion so far: Love $\subseteq$ Person $x$ Person is not reflexive or irreflexive because we don't know if the person loves himself. 
It can be a partial order as it contains minimal and maximal elements (in case $x$ do or don't love $y$).

It's hard to say if it's transitive because theres only two elements.

Can anyone help me out and describe why/why not it's an equivalence relation, partial order or total/linear order?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is transitive; if Alice loves Bob and Bob loves Carl, then this implies in no way that Alice loves Carl. And: what a sweet world it would be if only it was symmetric :-)

Comment: Why only two elements ? Consider as "universe" the totality of persons.

Comment: See [Partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set): reflexive, antisymm and transitive.

Comment: And see [Equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation): reflexive, symm and transitive.

Comment: The key point is *transitivity*: if we agree that "love" is **not** transitive, we have enough info to conclude.

Comment: "It can be a partial order as it contains minimal and maximal elements" No. If it isn't reflexive or transitive, it's not a partial order. Also, to be a partial order, it must be anti-symmetric (A loves B and B loves A then A=B) Does it contain minimal and maximal elements? Minimal elements would be the ones who are not loved by anyone; maximal, those who love none. Perhaps...

Answer (score 20):

If we supposed that Love was a partial order then we immediately run into issues with anti-symmetry. To be precise; if $x$ loves $y$ and $y$ loves $x$ we have the equations $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, thus by the anti-symmetry axiom we have $x=y$ and so $x$ and $y$ are the same person. Assuming that you don't take the narcissistic view that people only love themselves I would say this does not hold always. A total order would also run into the same problem.

As for it being an equivalence relation I would say no as it fails on all 3 criteria:

- Reflexivity: This assumes that everyone loves themselves, something I would say is unfortunately not true for everyone
- Symmetry: This says that if you love someone then that person must love you back. If this was true life would indeed be more simple.
- Transitivity: This states that if $a$ loves $b$ and $b$ loves $c$ then $a$ loves $c$ also. If this was true then love triangles wouldn't be so much of a big deal and Hollywood would have an even smaller list of plot lines to draw from.

If I had to categorise I would say your best bet is to think of Love being a directed graph with People as the vertices and an edge from $a$ to $b$ representing $a$ loves $b$.

Comment: I would love it if love was an equivalence relation with one equivalence class, on the set of all people. $+1$.

Comment: [directed graph](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LoveChart) :) +1

Comment: Actually, you could also hold that no two people love each other to get a partial order, not only that people only love themselves. (Indeed, if everybody only loved themselves, that would be an amazingly useless order relation.)

Comment: @CandiedOrange -1 TvTropes link without a TvTropes warning

Comment: @JohnDvorak Needs more **bold**.

Comment: Why do you say it’s unfortunate that not everyone loves themselves?  I would have thought that narcissism is generally a bad thing?

Comment: @eggyal I feel that having a certain level of love for yourself is healthy so I guess it is a level of degree

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг One love :)